# Quirks mode compatible lightbox? (IE)

Tags: jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, lightbox, colorbox, quirks-mode

I'm attempting to add a lightbox to an older website. This site will only display correctly in IE 8 with quirks mode on. Given this constraint, are there any lightbox plugins that function correctly? Are there workarounds for plugins that *don't* support quirks mode?

I've tried ColorBox with no success (the [ColorBox FAQ](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-doctype) states outright that quirks mode is not supported).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is virtually *nothing* available today that is intended to work correctly with Quirks mode.

Quirks mode was obsolete in 2001 -- it's basically an IE5-compatibility mode. If your code is still using it, then it's got a serious problem. By far the best answer would be to upgrade your site not to use quirks mode any more.

The good news is that this actually isn't difficult, if you only need to support IE8 and above, because IE8 supports a CSS feature called [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing). (This doesn't work in IE6 or IE7, which is why quirks mode has lingered so long, but it's fine in IE8)

`box-sizing` is a standard CSS feature that works in all browsers, and allows you to specify the box model to work like quirks mode.

The box model is the primary difference between quirks mode and standards mode, so in order to make a site written for quirks mode work in all browsers, simply set the `box-sizing` across the whole site: the following code should do it:

```
* {
   -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing:     border-box;
    box-sizing:        border-box;
}
```

You can then add the doctype and put the site into standards mode, and it should continue to work as before.

Once you've done that, you should be able to start using some modern browser features and up-to-date script libraries like the one you're asking about.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still need to maintain old web applications for the time being, so quirks mode will be kicking around for a little while longer. That begs the question however: do you think there is any risk that quirks mode will cease to be supported in new browser versions (any time in the near-future, that is)?

Comment: @JPistone: Yes: a very big risk -- IE9 already dropped support for quirks mode by default, unless you explicitly kick it back to compatibility mode. IE10 won't support it at all. And of course, no other browser has ever supported quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like slimbox support quirks mode, but I don't try it myself. http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2